# How to calculate count of business days between two dates?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to calculate count of business days (working days) between two given dates. Business days are all days of the week except Saturday and Sunday. I'm not considering holidays into this count.

How to calculate count of business days between two dates ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`DayOfTheWeek`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.DayOfTheWeek) (from the `DateUtils` unit) and a counter, iterating through from the starting date to the ending date. (You'll also probably need a table of holidays, to exclude those from your count also.)

```
function BusinessDaysBetween(const StartDate, EndDate: TDateTime): Integer;
var
  CurrDate : TDateTime;
begin
  CurrDate := StartDate;
  Result := 0;
  while (CurrDate <= EndDate) do
  begin
    // DayOfTheWeek returns 1-5 for Mon-Fri, so 6 and 7 are weekends
    if DayOfTheWeek(CurrDate) < 6 then
      Inc(Result);
    CurrDate := CurrDate + 1;
  end;
end;
```

You can enhance this a little by not worrying about the order of the parameters (in other words, it doesn't matter if start is before end or end is before start, the function will still work):

```
function BusinessDaysBetween(const FirstDate, SecondDate: TDateTime): Integer;
var
  CurrDate : TDateTime;
  StartDate, EndDate: TDateTime;
begin
  if SecondDate > FirstDate then
  begin
    StartDate := FirstDate;
    EndDate := SecondDate;
  end
  else
  begin
    StartDate := SecondDate;
    EndDate := FirstDate;
  end;

  CurrDate := StartDate;
  Result := 0;

  while (CurrDate <= EndDate) do
  begin
    if DayOfTheWeek(CurrDate) < 6 then
      Inc(Result);
    CurrDate := CurrDate + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I see thank you...I don't need holidays since they will not affect the turnaround times significantly..but weekends are problem. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I used almost the same function..works great. there are way too may specimens so if few have issue with holidays they will not affect the overall..thank you.

Comment: It would be nice to do this without a loop.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: +1. I had that on my to do list just for fun, but LU RD and user1008646 beat me to it. :)

Comment: Sardukar: You should change your accepted answer to either the one posted by @LURD or user1008648. Both are considerably faster than my solution. (user10008646's is slightly faster, but IMO LURD's is easier to read and maintain later.)

Comment: @KenWhite found a bug... "while (CurrDate < EndDate) do" should be "while (CurrDate <= EndDate) do" otherwise if EndDate is a business day, it's not counted.

Comment: @JohnEasley: Yes, you're right. Edited to fix in both cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

```
function BusinessDaysSinceFixedDate ( const nDate : tDateTime ) : integer;
const
  Map : array [ -6 .. 6 ] of integer
      = (  0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ); 
var
  X : integer;
begin
  X := trunc ( nDate );
  Result := 5 * ( X div 7 ) + Map [ X mod 7 ];
end;

function BusinessDaysBetweenDates ( const nStartDate : tDateTime;
                                    const nEndDate   : tDateTime ) : integer;
begin
  Result :=   BusinessDaysSinceFixedDate ( nEndDate )
            - BusinessDaysSinceFixedDate ( nStartDate );
end;
```

The routine BusinessDaysSinceFixedDate calculates the number of business days since a fixed date. The specific date, which is irrelevant, is Monday, 25 December, 1899.
It simply counts the number of weeks that have passed (X div 7) and multiplies that by 5. 
Then it adds an offset to correct based on the day of the week. 
Note that (X mod 7) will return a negative value for a negative date, i.e. a date before 30 December, 1899.

The routine BusinessDaysBetweenDates simply calls BusinessDaysSinceFixedDate for the start and end date and subtracts one from the other.

Comment: +1. You could add `Abs` to the Result of `BusinessDaysBetweenDates` (so the result of Days will be positive always).

Answer (score 12):

Without looping all days and input parameters not depending on order.

```
Uses DateUtils,Math;

function WorkingDaysBetween( const firstDate,secondDate : TDateTime) : Integer;
var
  startDate,stopDate : TDateTime;
  startDow,stopDow : Integer;
begin
  if (firstDate < secondDate) then
  begin
    startDate := firstDate;
    stopDate := secondDate;
  end
  else
  begin
    startDate := secondDate;
    stopDate := firstDate;
  end; 
  startDow := DayOfTheWeek(startDate);
  stopDow := DayOfTheWeek(stopDate);
  if (stopDow >= startDow) then
    stopDow := Min(stopDow,6)
  else
    Inc(stopDow,5); 

  Result := 
    5*WeeksBetween(stopDate,startDate) + 
    (stopDow - Min(startDow,6));
end;
```

Comment: +1. Nice! I didn't have a chance to look at a non-looping solution - now I definitely don't need to do so. :-)

Comment: I get different results from the other two, with your function, if I test `dt1 := Now` and `dt2 := IncYear(Now, 3)`.

Comment: @kobik, thanks. The correct day numbering function is of course `DayOfTheWeek()`.